# Bounty Leaderboard - Do we need it?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I answered [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/who-or-what-is-this-so-user/37110#37110) with a bounty leaderboard.

To the question, should the site have an area where you can see a bounty leaderboard (monthly, yearly)? Yay, nay, waffles?

Comment: Waffles, definitely waffles.

Comment: A leaderboard for bounty earned. bounty given or both?

Comment: If anyone is really curious to know, [senshin](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/11293/senshin) has made a [Bounty (Spent) Leaderboard](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/284343/top-bounty-spenders#) using data provided by the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an obvious benefit to SO to having a bounty leaderboard.  The bounty questions get plenty of exposure as it is.  Sure, it's a nice bit of statistics, and some people might get a warm fuzzy feeling pretending to be Han Solo, but is the impact on SO positive, neutral, or negative?

Comment: Pollyanna, I thought making people happy was your *modus vivendi*, nonetheless waffles agrees, I do not think there is enough scale here to make the list too interesting.

Answer (score 0):

We should have a bounty leaderboard if only to expose me as a greedy, greedy bastard.  It's the only way I'll learn.