# Bountyhunter Badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty Hunter badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges)

After seeing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37373/bounty-leaderboard-do-we-need-it) I was thinking that a Bountyhunter badge would be nice, like the tag-specific badges, 400 votes for a silver, 1000 for a gold.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1158#1158

Comment: @squillman, I searched but I didn't have a space in Bountyhunter.  Maybe we could get a badge for weak search-fu.

Comment: I'd be in the race to earn it first...

Comment: Just a plain old bronze for having won one, and make it re-winnable, would be nice.